# Jquery isn't removing table row from table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have JQuery code where a user can 'clone' a row if they click the checkbox, otherwise if they 'uncheck' it, I want it to remove the cloned rows.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.tr_clone input.part-class').change(function () {

                let Id = $(this).attr('id');
                let partId = $(this).attr('data-partId');

                if ($(this).prop("checked") == true){
                    // remove cloned row
                    $(Id + 'clone').remove();

                    $("#AllTxt").hide();
                    $("#editQty").show();
                }
                else {
                    var $tr = $(this).closest('.tr_clone');
                    var $clone = $tr.clone();
                    $clone.find('td');
                    $tr.after($clone);
                    $($clone).find(".part-class").hide();
                    $clone.find('input[type="radio"]').attr("name", function (el) { return el.name + 'clone' });
                    $clone.attr('id', (Id) + "clone");


                    $("#AllTxt").show();
                    $("#editQty").hide();               
                }

            });
        });
```

But this isn't removing the cloned row. Why is this?

Comment: Because the change event is only listened on elements that are present at runtime. Your cloned elements are not present at runtime, that’s why. You should probably listen to the change event bubbling up to a parent element that is already present at runtime, eg `$('table').on('change', '.tr_clone', function() {});` or the likes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#' + Id + 'clone').remove();
```

Looks like a classic selector problem